# make forever identify restart faster

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm using forever with my node.js site during development, such that it restarts the site on specific code changes. forever is a little slow to identify that files have changed and a restart is required. How can I make it detect that faster?

By the way node-supervisor works much faster, but I cannot use it for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster, try to reduce the amount of files 'forever' has to monitor.

Create a file called .foreverignores which is similar to .gitignore
inside .foreverignores add all the folders that you can ignore specially

```
node_modules/
```

Another solution is to just watch one file for example

```
forever -w app.js app.js
```

It depends on your needs.